# Promise hangs when calling "then"

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I'm following the sequelize getting started tutorial [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html).

One thing I find strange is that my node.js program never exit after calling `then`.

Here's my code:

```
// testSequelize.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

let CONN_STRING = `mysql://userName:password@127.0.0.1:3306/databaseName`;

var sequelize = new Sequelize(CONN_STRING, {
    logging: false
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

And the result of executing `node testSequelize.js` is

```
node testSequelize.js
Connection has been established successfully.
```

The program just hangs there, it does not exit. I mean I cannot see the command prompt after the execution.

Does anyone know why it never exit?

The versions of my `node`, `mysql2`, and `sequelize` are 6.2.2, 1.3.5, and 4.2.1 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exit because the connection is open, try closing it:

```
...
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  sequelize.close();
})
...
```